# Allowing an empty (epsilon) transition in a PDA

Tags: formal-languages, pushdown-automata

I'm trying to allow an empty transition in a PDA for the following language:

- Alphabet: $Σ = \{a, b, c\}$
- Language: $L = \{ a^ib^j \mid i \neq j \} \cdot \{ c \}^\ast$

Examples of words in $L$:

- $\varepsilon$
- $aabccc$
- $abbccc$

Not in $L$:

- $abcc$
- $aabbc$

Here is what I came up with:

[image: PDA]

The diagram above uses JFLAP - where the symbol $Z$ reflects the empty stack. The symbol $λ$ is the empty symbol $ϵ$.

It accepts everything as it should, but I don't know how to let epsilon get through. `q7` to `q8` is when there is more `b` than `a`. So there should be a way to allow `q7` to `q9` where `a` is more than `b` but also epsilon can get through. Thoughts? I would like to simply set epsilon through but than `aabbc` can get through easily enough.

Comment: With letting "epsilon get through" do you mean accepting the empty word?

Comment: @dkaeae Sorry yeah, meant accepting the empty word

Comment: @Apass.Jack You're right, fixed to clarify

Comment: Is the $x,y;z$ notation on the state transitions supposed to mean the PDA reads input symbol $x$ and stack symbol $y$ followed by writing $z$ to the stack? Then why is there a symbol $Z$ in the transition from $q_7$ to $q_8$ being read from the stack (if no such symbol was pushed previously)?

Comment: Is $Z$ used to symbolize the end of the stack? Do you use $\lambda$ as $\epsilon$?

Comment: @phan801 I'm using JFLAp, and yes they use $Z$ to symbolize end and $λ$ for $ϵ$

Comment: @dkaeae I'm using [JFLAP](http://www.jflap.org/) to simulate the PDA and run/experiment with it, they use $Z$ as the end of stack symbol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some key points:

- The only case where you want to accept $\epsilon$ is when you haven't had any other input and your stack is empty. Therefore you need an accepting state right at the beginning.
- You need to take into consideration inputs such as: $bac, aac,...$ that will never result in an accepting state, or $abbb$ that results in an accepting state without containing any $c$'s
- If you get a $b$ and your stack is empty you have more $b$'s than $a$'s so you need an accepting state
- If you get a $c$ and and your stack is not empty you have more $a$'s than $b$'s so you need an accepting state
- You reject everything else.

[image: This works]

Comment: Didn't think it would be this complicated, thanks! I do question how $λ, Z : Z$ works? Wouldn't this mean we can put anything in (i.e. a) and it would then accept it? If that's the case would an epsilon transition between $q7$ and $q9$ work as well?

Comment: I'm sorry, you're right! You don't need $\lambda,Z : Z$ at all. You just enter at $q_0$ which is an accepting state. I'll edit

Comment: Another question, from $q4$ to $q5$, does having the $λ, λ:λ$ transition mean anything can go there? Would that mean you can sneak in an $a$ in there and get it accepted?

Comment: You're right, once ageain. See the edit and let me know if something else doesn't seem right